# Replicate the right justification that ls does when using ls twice

Tags: formatting, ls, text-to-column

If I have two files, `tmp.txt` and `tmp.pdf`, one large and one small, when I type `ls -al tmp.*` everything is nicely right justified and I get this output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon 615316 Oct 17 20:55 tmp.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon      0 Oct 17 20:55 tmp.txt
```

For a reason that doesn't matter, I want to be able to write the output of two separate `ls -al` commands to a file, then `cat` the file  and obtain the same output.   But of course, if I do this:

```
ls -al tmp.txt > foo
ls -al tmp.pdf >> foo
```

and then `cat foo`, I get this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon 0 Oct 17 20:55 tmp.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon 615316 Oct 17 20:55 tmp.pdf
```

Is there a way of mimicking the justified output that `ls -al` produces?    Obviously, I can use `wc -c tmp.pdf` etc to figure out which output is largest, but how would I translate that information into code that would put the requisite number of spaces before the 0 in the first line?     Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just use [`column`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html)

```
$ (ll tmp.small; ll tmp.big) | column -t
-rw-r--r--  1  myuser  myuser  0       Oct  18  11:24  tmp.small
-rw-r--r--  1  myuser  myuser  113616  Oct  18  11:42  tmp.big
```

However if your file names contain spaces then those names won't be printed correctly. If your `column` supports the `-l` option then the simplest fix is to change to `column -t -l 9` to limit the total number of columns to 9. Another workaround is to use [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to simulate `ls` output

```
$ (
> stat --printf="%A\t%h\t%U\t%G\t%s\t%y\t%n\n" "tmp with space.txt"
> stat --printf="%A\t%h\t%U\t%G\t%s\t%y\t%n\n" tmp.small
> stat --printf="%A\t%h\t%U\t%G\t%s\t%y\t%n\n" tmp.big
> ) | column -t -s $'\t'
-rw-r--r--  1  myuser  myuser  1307    2020-10-18 12:08:45.360000000 +0700  tmp with space.txt
-rw-r--r--  1  myuser  myuser  0       2020-10-18 11:24:21.650000000 +0700  tmp.small
-rw-r--r--  1  myuser  myuser  113616  2020-10-18 11:42:04.150000000 +0700  tmp.big
```

Files with tabs or newlines in their names still don't work though. You may try to change the delimiter to null with `stat --printf="%A\0%h\0%U\0%G\0%s\0%Y\0%n\n" tmp* | column -t -s $'\0' -l 9` but somehow my `column` doesn't recognize `\0` as the delimiter. Not sure about other columns versions, just try it on your PC and see

Comment: Fabulous, thanks very much.     I do everything I can to avoid spaces in file names, and certainly newlines, so the first solution works fine.    It's not important, but i'm curious about `ll` which is not supported on my ubuntu 18.04 platform, nor can I `apt` it.    Could you tell me where it came from please?

Comment: @LeoSimon `ll` is the alias for `ls -alF` which exists by default in Ubuntu and most distros I've used